# Serial calculation from total value in Pandas or Python

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a Pandas df:

```
  Number
0     -30
1       2
2      12
3      -6
4      22
5      -3
6     -10
```

My starting value, the total, is 1500.

I would like to sum each row value from the previous one, and the starting value is 1500, to get this:

```
  Number  Path
0     -30  1470
1       2  1472
2      12  1484
3      -6  1478
4      22  1500
5      -3  1497
6     -10  1487
```

I tried with df.diff() but it cannot calculate it from 1500 and begin the operation from there.

Is there another way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cumsum` then add the total:

```
total = 1500
df['Path'] = total+df['Number'].cumsum()
```

---

```
   Number  Path
0     -30  1470
1       2  1472
2      12  1484
3      -6  1478
4      22  1500
5      -3  1497
6     -10  1487
```

Answer (score 1):

Your task can be broken down into

1. Calculate the cummulative sum
2. Offset the sum by 1500 (similar to translation of origin if you can relate to geometry)

```py
df.Number.cumsum() + 1500
```